# How can I mimick nhibernate's repository pattern with linq2sql?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-sql

I was reading this blog entry:

> https://web.archive.org/web/20110503184234/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/08/the-repository-pattern.aspx

I like how they made a interface that has all the basic CRUD queries for you, and you can use it accross all your entities/tables.

Can this also be done with linqtosql as well?

---

#### Code:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    public ISession Session { get { return UnitOfWork.CurrentSession; } }
    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return Session.Get<T>(id);
    }

    public ICollection<T> FindAll()
    {
        return Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).List<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T product)
    {
        Session.Save(product);
    }

    public void Remove(T product)
    {
        Session.Delete(product);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are [several](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=linq+to+sql+repository+pattern&aq=0&oq=linq+to+sql+reposit&aqi=g2) attempts to implement this pattern using LINQ to SQL.